# My inner join resulted in the repetition of many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, unique

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT 
  CAN.Cycle
, CAN.FECCandID
, CAN.CID
, CAN.FirstLastP
, CAN.Party
, CAN.DistIDRunFor
, CAN.DistIDCurr
, CAN.CurrCand
, CAN.CycleCand
, CAN.CRPICO
, CAN.RecipCode
, CAN.NoPacs
FROM Cands16 AS CAN
JOIN MercerRobert_Indivs AS MER
ON CAN.CID = MER.RecipID
```

My goal was to return every row from the Cands16 in which CID = RecipID. This was the result:

[image: pic]

While the MER table does have rows with multiple incidences of the same value for RecipID, every incidence of CID in the Cands16 table is unique. I do not want these duplicate rows resulting from my query. So what should I do? I am using SQL Server 2016 Management Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing you do not use any columns from MER, it seems you just want to know whether there exists such id in MER. So the easiest would be to remove the join:

```
select
   CAN.Cycle
   , CAN.FECCandID
   , CAN.CID
   , CAN.FirstLastP
   , CAN.Party
   , CAN.DistIDRunFor
   , CAN.DistIDCurr
   , CAN.CurrCand
   , CAN.CycleCand
   , CAN.CRPICO
   , CAN.RecipCode
   , CAN.NoPacs 
from Cands16 CAN
where exists (
    select * 
    from MercerRobert_Indivs MER 
    where CAN.CID = MER.RecipID
  ) ;
```

Comment: This worked! I have never seen this `where exists` before. I will try to learn how to use it for future use.

Comment: glad to hear. I wonder whether there is some advantage over the other solution with `JOIN` and `DISTINCT`, or I was just lucky to post first syntactically correct solution. I think `DISTINCT` usually forces sorting and that can be slow, but I guess the sorting can be optimized away in this case,

Answer (score 1):

Your example SQL uses a simple join.

SQL Server (Transact-SQL) JOINS are used to retrieve data from multiple tables. A SQL Server JOIN is performed whenever two or more tables are joined in a SQL statement.

There are 4 different types of SQL Server joins:

- SQL Server INNER JOIN (or sometimes called simple join)
- SQL Server LEFT OUTER JOIN (or sometimes called LEFT JOIN)
- SQL Server RIGHT OUTER JOIN (or sometimes called RIGHT JOIN)
- SQL Server FULL OUTER JOIN (or sometimes called FULL JOIN)

See [this link](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php) for more details and explanations of the different joins you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  CAN.Cycle
, CAN.FECCandID
, CAN.CID
, CAN.FirstLastP
, CAN.Party
, CAN.DistIDRunFor
, CAN.DistIDCurr
, CAN.CurrCand
, CAN.CycleCand
, CAN.CRPICO
, CAN.RecipCode
, CAN.NoPacs
FROM Cands16 AS CAN
-- the same RecipID can occur several times in MercerRobert_Indivs
-- so make sure this is not the case before joining ...
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT RecipID FROM MercerRobert_Indivs) AS MER
ON CAN.CID = MER.RecipID
```

Comment: I received an error saying there is incorrect syntax near the word 'FROM'. It also appears that you have a `)` without an accompanying `(`

Comment: The close parenthesis after `RecipID` was one too many. Corrected now.